# Generate presentation with Python

Tags: python, powerpoint, openxml, openoffice-impress

I'm working with data processing and want to generate PowerPoint or OpenOffice Impress presentation with some data analysis directly from Python. Is there any libraries for Python to do that? I'm using Unix enviroment.

Comment: I know it's not an answer for your question - but there's a  LaTeX package called **beamer**, which can be used to produce a coherent and aesthetical presentations in PDF format. Most of the presentations in my University are done that way.

Comment: Yes, i know it and this is an option too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

You can use the `odf` library.

http://opendocumentfellowship.com/projects/odfpy

The document you'll get will be in ODF format but you can later convert it to PPT using [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/).

Comment: Cool! Do you know something similar for Microsoft Office Open XML? Like `phppowerpoint`, but for `Python`.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like this is starting to come along well: https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/